# Why I can't able to update the variable value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ajax

Okay I followed [how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30180679/4374121)

No matter what I can't able to update variable tag.. How to update tag

```
function foo() {
    // RETURN the promise
    return fetch("stack-url").then(function(response){
        return response.json(); // process it inside the `then`
    });
}


self.addEventListener('push', function(event){
    var title = 'Featured Message';
    var body = 'StackOverFlow Question Got Featured Post';
    var tag = 'this-is-dummy-tag';

    foo().then(function(response){
      console.log('this is then result ', response);
      var tag = response.question_id;
      return tag;
        // access the value inside the `then`
    })

    event.waitUntil(
      self.registration.showNotification(title, {
        body:body,
        tag:tag,
      })
    );
});
```

Comment: None of the examples shows how to update an outer variable with data from the `.then` callback. So why are you doing that? At the moment you are accessing `tag`, the `.then` callback has not been executed yet. That's what the question you linked to is all about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try including `event.waitUntil` second `.then()` chained , set `tag` using returned value from first `.then()` ; or setting `tag` at first then ; removing trailing comma `,` following last value at `event.waitUntil` object

```
    foo().then(function(response){
      console.log('this is then result ', response);
      var tag = response.question_id;
      return tag;
        // access the value inside the `then`
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      event.waitUntil(
        self.registration.showNotification(title, {
          body:body,
          tag:data
        })
      );
    })
```

---

```
    foo().then(function(response){
      console.log('this is then result ', response);
      var tag = response.question_id;

        // access the value inside the `then`
      event.waitUntil(
        self.registration.showNotification(title, {
          body:body,
          tag:tag
        })
      );
    })
```

Comment: `Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'waitUntil' on 'ExtendableEvent': The event handler is already finished.`

Comment: looks like the error is there but it's working ... How to get rid of the error

Comment: @Rosini _"looks like the error is there but it's working ... How to get rid of the error "_ Not certain ? Tried returning `foo` at `event.waitUntil` ? Appear accepts function that returns a `Promise` see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ExtendableEvent/waitUntil